# Ubuntu upstart init script not working

Tags: linux, bash, nginx, terminal

I'm following an nginx tutorial from [here](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-serve-flask-applications-with-uwsgi-and-nginx-on-ubuntu-14-04#create-an-upstart-script) and I created a `myproject.conf` file in `/etc/init/` as stated in the tutorial. The code is as follows:

```
description "uWSGI server instance configured to serve myproject"

start on runlevel [2345]
stop on runlevel [!2345]

setuid ec2-user
setgid www-data


env PATH=/home/ec2-user/login_test/venv/bin
chdir /home/ec2-user/login_test/oauth_login
exec uwsgi --ini wsgi.ini
```

When I tried to activate this by giving `sudo start myproject` it returns:

```
start: Unknown job: myproject
```

How can I get this to work?

Comment: did you put the file in /etc/init?

Comment: yes. it's there.

Comment: What’s your OS version? Upstart has been deprecated.

Comment: yeees, I just realised it's outdated... guess this question as a whole is invalid now. thank you for looking into it anyways.